# How to not lose work in git merge commits

Tags: git, git-merge, git-commit

We are using Git in our team for managing our codebase.

Occasionally, I've noticed we have cases where particular code changes are lost. I've tracked the issue down and it seems to be caused by merge commits:

1. A developer pulls in changes from origin to his local repo.
2. A merge commit is made. Since this is not committed automatically (by default), the developer makes a change to the merge commit (e.g: discarding a particular code file change).
3. The developer pushes to origin.

What is the proper way to protect ourselves from this scenario ?

Also, how can I restore the lost changes in the easiest way? I usually just manually  apply the changes again.

Comment: You can always rollback to the commit before the merge was done.

Comment: Most likely you're losing work because of mishandled merge conflicts.

Comment: Normally, developers should not discard changes from merge commits.

Answer (score 1):

I think in these kind of cases you should simply avoid merge commits. That means you simply need to rebase your work in top of the remote branch whenever you pull, for instance:

```
git pull origin master --rebase
```

You can configure this to be the default in your .gitconfig.

Comment: Are there any disadvantages to this approach ?

Comment: You can't have modified file to do this so you might need to stash your changes and unstash them after they are done. If your team struggles with merge conflict, this will not be a magic solution. However, I think this is more straighforward as the developer will add their work on top of what is already in the git repository.